# How to display content type field values in tab panel format?

Tags: nodes

I have created custom content type. I want to display it's data (field values) in tab panel format. is there any way to change it through CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im using the [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module for creating tabs. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to create blocks of tabbed content, specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding content display instantly, using jQuery. With the 6.x-2.x branch, this can be done in either ajax or non-ajax mode:
>
> - if you choose ajax mode for your Quick Tabs block (and this is chosen on an individual QT basis), only the content of the active tab will be loaded on page load and the content of the other tabs will be loaded via ajax on tab click (this is good for performance if you are loading, for example, several large views)
> - in non-ajax mode the tab content is just hidden / shown on tab-click. This latter method is an ideal way to do something like the Most Popular / Most Emailed stories tabs you see on many news websites, where it is used more as a space-saving device in your sidebar. If however, you want a QT block as the main content of your entire page, then the chances are that ajax mode will be more appropriate.
>
> Once created, the Quick Tabs blocks show up in your block listing, ready to be configured and enabled like other blocks. Multiple Quick Tabs blocks can be placed on a single page.
>
> For theming of the tabs, several styles have been provided for you to choose from (in the 7.x-3.x branch this functionality comes in a separate submodule, Quicktabs Tabstyles), along with the default option of no style, if you prefer to add your own theming instead.